# Inserting 1-32 bits into a 64 bit (8x8byte) buffer

Tags: c++, embedded, buffer, bit

I am trying to insert a value that is from 1 to 32 bits long into a buffer of 8 bytes (64 bits).

For example, I have 12 bit value that I want to insert into bit position 7 through 18.

The only way I can think of doing this is to cast my 12 bit value as a 64 bit value, shifting it, and then setting all the bits in my buffer that way, then separating my 64 bit value into 8 bytes.  There might be other data in the 8 byte frame...  **Is there a better way to do this?**

Will include some sample code below.

```
byte tx_msg[8] = {0};
uint32_t random_value = 77;
uint64_t buffer = 0;
// In this example, start point is bit 7, length is 12.

buffer = (uint64_t)random_value << (64 - 12 - 7);
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    tx_msg[7-i] = tx_msg[7-i] | buffer >> (i*8);
}
```

Comment: I would rotate value, then | and & with inverted value in case your CPU can work with UInt64 ?

Comment: @Tom yea it can use long long or unsigned long long 64 bit value.  It'll slow me down, so thats why I'm looking fora possible better solution.  There might be a pointer solution with static casting to this, but I'm not great with pointers :/.  What do you mean by rotating value?

Comment: Be careful with the simple types like `long long`, because their length is actually not  garantueed. Use `uin64_t` if a length of 64bit is required.

Comment: @churill right, I use uint64_t in my code.  I don't know if this is the right solution still.  Looking for alternatives.

Comment: You simply can't write this program without mentioning endianess/the expected byte order in the byte buffer.

Comment: Yeah, I read your comment were you talked about long long, but I see, you already know that, sorry. I think in the loop you actually reverse the order of elements or something?

Comment: @Lundin it is big endian.  Even if it was little endian, I can change the byte order.

Comment: Do you really mean "insert" or rather simply "copy"?  "insert" suggest shifting the existing bits right.

Comment: _"a better way"_ in what sense? - More reusable, more generic, simpler, more maintainable, easier to comprehend, smaller code, faster code?  "better" is a matter of opinion.  What are your _requirements_.

Comment: Note that if you are using an ARM Cortex-M3 or M4 and the object is in bit-bandable memory, you can do this with `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to clearly define the bit ordering.  Assuming bit-ordering LSB first:

```
| Byte0  | Byte1  | ...
-----------------------
|01234567|01234567| ...
```

Such that for example:

```
|00000001|10000000|
```

would be `Byte0 == 0x80` and `Byte1 == 0x08` (because the hex representation is MSB first).

Then I would suggest a more general-purpose interface:

```
void copyBits( uint8_t* dest, int offset, uint32_t bits, int length ) ;
```

Where `length` bits from `bits` (starting from the LSB) will be copied to `offset` bits in the `dest`.

A simple, (but sub-optimal in terms of performance) method is to copy bit-by-bit thus:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void copyBits( uint8_t* dest, int offset, uint32_t bits, int length )
{
    for( int b = 0; b < length; b++ )
    {
        int source_bit = (bits & (0x01 << b)) == 0 ? 0 : 1 ;

        div_t bit_dest = div( offset + b, 8 ) ;
        if( source_bit == 0 )
        {
            dest[bit_dest.quot] &= ~(0x01 << bit_dest.rem) ;
        }
        else
        {
            dest[bit_dest.quot] |= (0x01 << bit_dest.rem) ;
        }
    }
}
```

This can be improved by working with whole bytes and masking in the head and tail, but it is more complicated, so unless performance is critical or you are copying very many bits frequently, I suggest that simple and generic might be sufficient.  Either way, the take home is the generic reusability of the function rather then hard coding for specific parameters.  Importantly it is not restricted to 64 bit destination buffers.  It could be adaptes so it is not restricted to maximum 32bit source fields.

Example usage:

```
uint8_t x[8] = {0};

insertBits( x, 7, 0x555, 12 ) ;

for( int i = 0; i < sizeof( x ); i++ )
{
    printf( "%02X", x[i] ) ;
}
```

Results in

```
80AA020000000000
```

which in binary in LSB first bit-order is:

```
LSB --->
0000 0001 0101 0101 0100 0000 0000 ...
        ^-------------^
           0x555 (12 bits) copied here
```

Comment: Bit0 = 0x01 universally and hardware independent, unless perhaps you've been reading certain confusing IBM or PowerPC manuals :) Byte order is another story of course. There's no telling what CPU the OP is using, but in case of ARM, I would always assume Bit0 = 0x01 and byte order= little endian, unless it's some very exotic case. Even the "big endian camp" with NXP/Freescale & Renesas use little endian on their ARM, as far as I know.

Comment: The byte order is not an issue when using a byte array rather then a `uint64_t` as in the question.  The bit order may be an issue if for example the data is being prepared for transmission and the transmission medium may be either LSB or MSB first.  You might in some cases reverse the bit order in order to realise the correct transmission order.  Also I mentioned it for clarity because when presented in hex it can be confusing.

Comment: It is, since you need to know where to store the MS byte from the uint64_t. As for transmission medium that's another story, they can indeed be LSB first. But inside the MCU, bit 0 is always 0x01.

Comment: Hi @Clifford, thanks for the reply and sorry for getting back to the answer late.  I was able to use your suggested method to form my solution.  Sorry for the very poorly written question, but your very detailed answer was able to give me a good understanding of the problem.  I was actually using MSB needed to copy bits in from the right, but your method only needed a few changes.  Thanks again!